# People picker finds group, then says no exact match found

Tags: 2007, document-library, permissions, people-picker, people-search

I'm trying to add a group to a document library to give them permission to see it. If I type the group name and ask SP to check it, it says

```
No exact match was found
```

If I search the address book it will find the group, I presss "Add", "Ok", after about 10 seconds it adds the group name underlined. I choose the level of permission, choose whether to send an email or not and then press "Ok". The page then jumps back to the top wih the same error as above. Most frustrating!

I've successfully added an individual user to this library and edited the permissions of exsisting groups so it seems to be a problem with authenticating the group name rather than a problem with the library itself.

I've found a few similar questions on SE but I only have client side functionality

**Update**: One  of the higher admins (who has acess to Central Administration etc) thinks it is a sync issue between SharePoint and Activve Directory

**Update**: I can add other groups to this library but the group I cannot add was created after the library stopped inheriting permissions, I think this may have something to do with it?

Comment: I was in the process of typing in a question when your question popped up as a possible similar quest. It ain't similar, it is EXACTLY the same problem I'm having. Identical.

While I see there are no replies yet, by any chance have you found a solution? I'm 99% ready to submit a ticket in with MS and $ for the answer, if one exists.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one! No unfortunately I have no solution. I've had to add all the users to the list individually which isn't too bad as there are only about 12 but it's not ideal for bigger groups. If you do get an answer from MS I would really appreciate it if you post it as an answer here :-)

Comment: I haven't called MS yet, but for now did find a kludge. My workaround, while not optimal was this:

 - At the site collection level, I dumped and re-created the group, and at that time, assigned the desired permission level to it.
 - I enabled inheritance on the desired list permissions, which brought in all the groups for the collection, including the desired group with the desired permission level
 - I then broke inheritance on the list permissions, and removed all the other unwanted groups.

While not optimal, this did get me out of my immediate jam.

Comment: Yes I did think something like that might work but I don't have access to do that. Rather than trying to explain all that to one of the higher admins it was easier for me to just add my users individually as it wasn't a big group

Comment: @AlanM  Did you ever find another solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I've just come to accept it as another barefoot step on the walkway of broken glass that is Microsoft SharePoint.